# Customized ConfigurationSection in Derived Project

Tags: .net, customization, configurationsection

I created a base library where my customized configuration section is located. This works fine so far - also in derived libraries:

```
<MySection>
    <Tooling>
       <add Key="asdf" Value="bla/>
    </Tooling>
</MySection>
```

Now i want to modify the configuration section "MySection" in a new derived library with some properties. but i always get an exception that the section 'SpecialTooling' is not known - because it is defined in the derived class.

Is this possible todo?

Comment: Curious, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: the solution was that i have to specify an extra section and define where to find this section ( dll Location ) afterwards it worked fine.